# Get username with Windows Authentication and anonymous authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

I have 2 MVC applications that share a common database. One sits on the Internet server and uses anonymous authentication with a GateKeeper database and the other sits on the Intranet server and uses Windows authentication with Active Directory.

I want to implement an audit trail by overriding the SaveChanges method of EntityFramework. In this override, I want to record the username of the logged in user. On the external site it will be the email address and on the intranet site it will be the AD account name.

The applications both use integrated security to connect to the database, so they both run on a generic application pool account that has access to the database.

I've tried using both `Environment.UserName` and System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, but both give me the application pool user account, one simply without the domain:

```
UserName = Environment.UserName //{ result = CAPETOWN\global-custom }
UserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name //{ result = global-custom }
```

How do I get the usernames I desire

Comment: You probably should not do it in this way, give the application (in this case the web app), the responsibility of determining and setting the username, not your data/repository layer, which should only be responsible for saving/retrieving and validating data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
string UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Although it won't suit design if you have code in specific manner add more detail to your answer.

You can get URL of screen on which action taken 
    string _urlOfEntity = Url = HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath;

For overriding the SaveChanges() method you can use

**Code for Auditing Edit Action:**

```
public int SaveChanges(object _olderInstance)
    {


        foreach (var ent in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified || p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added || p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted))
        {
            // For each changed record, get the audit record entries and add them
            //foreach (XmlTesst x in GetAuditRecordsForChange(ent))
            //{
            this.XmlTessts.Add(GetAuditRecordsForChange(ent));

            //}
        }



        // Call the original SaveChanges(), which will save both the changes made and the audit records
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public XmlTesst GetAuditRecordsForChange(DbEntityEntry dbEntry)
    {
        string tableName, eventtype;
        XmlTesst XmlForReturn;


        if (dbEntry.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified)
        {
            TableAttribute tableAttr = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as TableAttribute;

            // Get table name (if it has a Table attribute, use that, otherwise get the pluralized name)
            tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : dbEntry.Entity.GetType().Name;
            XmlDocument XmlCurrentDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode rootNodeCurrent = XmlCurrentDoc.CreateElement(tableName);
            XmlCurrentDoc.AppendChild(rootNodeCurrent);

            XmlDocument XmlOldDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode rootNodeOld = XmlOldDoc.CreateElement(tableName);
            XmlOldDoc.AppendChild(rootNodeOld);

            foreach (string propertyName in dbEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
            {
                object CurrentValues = dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);
                object OriginalValues = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(_olderInstancea, null);

                if (!object.Equals(dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(_olderInstancea, null), CurrentValues) && (OriginalValues != null || CurrentValues != null))
                {

                    XmlNode userNodeCurrent = XmlCurrentDoc.CreateElement(propertyName);
                    userNodeCurrent.InnerText = CurrentValues.ToString();
                    rootNodeCurrent.AppendChild(userNodeCurrent);

                    XmlNode userNodeOld = XmlOldDoc.CreateElement(propertyName);
                    if (OriginalValues == null)
                    {
                        userNodeOld.InnerText = "Not Assigned ";
                        rootNodeOld.AppendChild(userNodeOld);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        userNodeOld.InnerText = OriginalValues.ToString();
                        rootNodeOld.AppendChild(userNodeOld);
                    }


                }
            }


            XmlForReturn = new XmlTesst() { OriginalXml = GetXMLAsString(XmlOldDoc), CurrentXml = GetXMLAsString(XmlCurrentDoc), EventType = "Edited", TimeofActivity = DateTime.Now, UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, Url = HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath, Screen = tableName };
            return XmlForReturn;
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can try this

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: It would be `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` It is not good design to introduce a dependency on HttpContext into a data/business logic/repository layer, it would simply fail if used in another context and would make it difficult to unit test.